# Main toolbar is not shown in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, toolbar, rcp, plugin.xml

I have an application on Eclipse RCP 3.x and tried to add a main toolbar via plugin.xml.

After running the application I don't see it, the toolbar is not visible.
I don't understand what's wrong in the code.

```xml
<menuContribution
    allPopups="false"
    locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
 <toolbar
       id="rcp.toolbar1">
    <command
          commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
          label="Save"
          style="push">
    </command>
    <command
          commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAll"
          id="rcp.menu.file.saveall"
          label="Save All"
          style="push">
    </command>
 </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
```

Comment: Are you using the GUI to make the tool bar? If you click on extensions, you should be able to create the toolbar without touching the code.

Comment: Are you creating the RCP application using an ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor? If so you need to create the toolbar in the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.

Comment: @greg-449
I have ApplicationWorkBenchAdvisor class, but i don't touch it.
All menus, parts and editors described in plugin.xml

Answer (score 0):

> I have ApplicationWorkBenchAdvisor class, but i don't touch it.

Like greg-449 already commented: Beside of [defining some toolbar elements](https://github.com/adam-taras/java-sandbox/commit/fbc2d2d52b65c9aaead43c46915c944e111b73a4) within the `plugin.xml`, you have also to [activate the toolbar](https://github.com/adam-taras/java-sandbox/commit/c1175c232b567462c94a0bb390092fc3bb7b56e8?diff=split) within your `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class - if created.